# Can only download HTTP/HTTPS URIs error

Tags: android, android-intent, android-download-manager

I am generating an excel sheet from search results in my app when user selects 'generate excel' option provided in my app overflow actionbar. I could save that file in the location "file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/tempfile.xls" without any problem but I would like to provide the generated excel sheet in the download menu via DownloadManager like this -

```
String filepath = "file://" + Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/tempfile.xls";
        Uri uriDownloadFile = Uri.parse(filepath );
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uriDownloadFile);
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "tempfile.xls");
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED); // to notify when download is complete
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();// if you want to be available from media players
        DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        manager.enqueue(request);
```

I tried to change the the local filepath to a uri using Uri.parse (second line of code above). However, I ended with the following error -

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only download HTTP/HTTPS URIs: file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/tempfile.xls
```

Comment: `DownloadManager` downloads files. It does not copy local files, as you are attempting.

Comment: I am not trying to copy local files. I am trying to present the local file via DownloadManager

Comment: "I am not trying to copy local files" -- you are trying to download a local file to a local file. I would consider that to be copying a local file.

Comment: oh okay. you are right. so, anything you can suggest in how I can accomplish what I am trying to achieve? Present a local file for download to user

Comment: I sincerely doubt that it is possible, unless you wanted to upload the file somewhere then download it using `DownloadManager`.

Comment: @Ajay Pleas read the entire question